# How do I get the SID / session of an arbitrary process?

Tags: winapi

I'm writing a program to enumerate through processes, and I want to find out the SID/user ID and session of which the specified process is running under (i.e. i *have* a PID/handle to process, I *want* the SID and session it's running under). Any clues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the SID, call OpenProcess to get the handle, then pass the handle to GetSecurityInfo().

For the session id, use ProcessIdToSessionId().

Answer (score 3):

WTSEnumerateProcesses works like gangbusters here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383831%28VS.85%29.aspx