# How to get the user name or owner of a process in .net

Tags: c#, .net, process

How can I find the owner of a given process in C#? The class System.Diagnostics.Process doesn't seem to have any properties or methods that will get me this information. I figure it must be available because it is shown in the Windows Task Manager under the "User Name" column.

My specific scenario involves finding the instance of a process (such as taskhost.exe) which is running as "Local Service". I know how to find all the instances of taskhost using

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("taskhost")
```

So now I just need to know how to identify the one which is running as local service.

Answer (score 8):

Use WMI to retrieve instances of the [Win32_Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa394372.aspx), then call the [GetOwner method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa390460.aspx) on each instance to get the domain name and user name of the user under which the process is running.  After adding a reference to the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.aspx) assembly, the following code should get you started:

```
// The call to InvokeMethod below will fail if the Handle property is not retrieved
string[] propertiesToSelect = new[] { "Handle", "ProcessId" };
SelectQuery processQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_Process", "Name = 'taskhost.exe'", propertiesToSelect);

using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(processQuery))
using (ManagementObjectCollection processes = searcher.Get())
    foreach (ManagementObject process in processes)
    {
        object[] outParameters = new object[2];
        uint result = (uint) process.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", outParameters);

        if (result == 0)
        {
            string user = (string) outParameters[0];
            string domain = (string) outParameters[1];
            uint processId = (uint) process["ProcessId"];

            // Use process data...
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle GetOwner() failure...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Handle property on the process and pass it to GetSecurityInfo through the P/Invoke layer to get the security information on the process.

It's the same as this question:

[How do I get the SID / session of an arbitrary process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559356/how-do-i-get-the-sid-session-of-an-arbitrary-process)

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try the code at [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/processownersid.aspx)

First result in google search for "C# get process owner"

Most likely the task manager uses the Win32 API via C to do this.  That process is also outlined in the link above.