# GetAccessControl(xxxxxx) return false results

Tags: c#, .net

I use     `File.GetAccessControl(ProcessName).GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier)).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).tostring();`
to get the owner of a process running in the task manager but it returns "Builtin\Administrators" while the process I queried was an installed program's running instance that is runnable without an administrative privilege. Why is that ? Besides, I expect a better string returned i.e "System" or "Local network service" instead of fake Builtin\Administrators.
  I tested this method with all other processes and I'm surprised to find only my opening notepad instance is supposed to be of my computer's username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are querying the file itself not the running process. You'll need to do something like this [How do I get the SID / session of an arbitrary process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559356/how-do-i-get-the-sid-session-of-an-arbitrary-process)